# from nodejs app mongose.save() block and doesn't do anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, centos7, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to use a very basic MongoDB method is to save a document on a database with mongoose.

1.I installed my MongoDB in centos 7

2.Create a database on the Mongo shell using: use mydatabase and insert a document inside it as normal.

3.Install mongoose and make a connection between my nodejs app and the MongoDB:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/goClass_test', {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});
```

4. test the connection and all is fine with:

```
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('DB Connected');
});
```

5. Import the model schema as normal:

`var { Classe } = require('../DBModels/GoClassDBModels/classes');`

6. try to add new document like this:

```
var newClasse = new Classe({
     label: 'hello',
     level: 'level',
   });
```

```
newClasse.save()
```

My Model is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var classSchema = new Schema({
  directeurId: {
    type: ObjectId,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  level: {
    type: String,
  },
  studentNbr: {
    type: String,
  },
});

var Classe = mongoose.model('Classes', classSchema);

module.exports = { Classe };
```

**SERVER.JS:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('server is started on 80');
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/goClass_test', {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});

console.log(mongoose.connection.host);
console.log(mongoose.connection.port);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('DB Connected');
});

db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

var { Classe } = require('../DBModels/GoClassDBModels/classes');

const goClasseRouteDirecteur = require('./GOClassRoutes/DirecteurRoutes/subRoutesClass');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser(['lakkini.com']));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.set(
    'Cache-Control',
    'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
  );
  next();
});

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static('/home/admin/SMS'));
app.use(express.static('/home/admin/assets'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('SMS/dashboard.hbs');
});

app.get('/classes', (req, res) => {
  res.render('SMS/classes.hbs');
});

app.get('/inscription', (req, res) => {
  res.render('SMS/inscriptions.hbs');
});

app.post('/saveClasse', (req, res) => {
  var newClasse = new Classe({
    label: 'hello',
    level: 'level',
  });
  console.log('im gonna save the new class');
  newClasse.save((err, response) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(response);
  });
});
```

**The problem is: nothing happened. No document has been inserted and no errors.
Can you suggest to me, please ?**

**PS: I'm trying to request from an HTTP server without HTTPS.**

**will that affect my requests nd block the save to the database?**

result:
[click to see the picture of the result please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRAHW.png)

Comment: How Is defined your model Classe?

Comment: @max i added the definition in the question please check.

Comment: Can you check whether the `save` method is throwing an error by adding a callback `newClasse.save((err, response) => { if (err) console.log(err); else console.log(response)});`

Comment: @Vishnu nothing happens. when i tried to add a pre('save') into the Classe model with a console, the console has shown as normal after that nothing happened...that confused really:  `classSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('presave function called');
  next();
});`

Comment: @Vishnu I added a result picture in the question. pelase check it.

Comment: Have you checked the database whether the records are inserted?. Unless you add the callback to `newClasse.save()` it will not log anything in the console

Comment: i already did that and added a callback to the .save() but nothing showed ! no error appears. i added this:  `newClasse.save((err, response) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(response);
  });`

Comment: How do you check whether no document has been inserted?

Comment: @thammada what do you mean? i did add a callback to the save function but without any error on the console, on the other hand, i added a pre-save on my model and it triggered as well but he save doesn't!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, but I don't understand why that.
the first structure was:

**

- DBModel

  - classes.js
- Server

  - server.js**

the structure right now:

**

- DBModel

  - classes.js
- server.js

**

I make out the server from that folder and all working fine...??

why that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the whole file was not given for mongoose connection and where save function is called , assuming you have structured it properly i'm giving my answer.
I was able to do this way,

The schema (same as yours) :

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = require("mongoose");
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var classSchema = new Schema({
  directeurId: {
    type: ObjectId,
  },
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  level: {
    type: String,
  },
  studentNbr: {
    type: String,
  },
});

var Classe = mongoose.model("Classes", classSchema);

module.exports = { Classe };
```

Function to insert:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/goClass_test", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });

  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));

  db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("DB Connected");
    var newClasse = new Classe({
      label: "hello",
      level: "level",
    });

    newClasse.save();
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

### SERVER.JS

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const http = require("http");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const _ = require("lodash");

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(80, () => {
  console.log("server is started on 80");
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/goClass_test", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});

console.log(mongoose.connection.host);
console.log(mongoose.connection.port);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("DB Connected");
});

db.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

var { Classe } = require("./models/Classe");

// const goClasseRouteDirecteur = require('./GOClassRoutes/DirecteurRoutes/subRoutesClass');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser(["lakkini.com"]));
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.set(
    "Cache-Control",
    "no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
  );
  next();
});

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
// app.use(express.static("/home/admin/SMS"));
// app.use(express.static("/home/admin/assets"));

// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//     res.render('SMS/dashboard.hbs');
//   });

//   app.get('/classes', (req, res) => {
//     res.render('SMS/classes.hbs');
//   });

//   app.get('/inscription', (req, res) => {
//     res.render('SMS/inscriptions.hbs');
//   });

app.post("/saveClasse", (req, res) => {
  var newClasse = new Classe({
    label: "hello",
    level: "level",
  });
  console.log("im gonna save the new class");

  newClasse.save((err, response) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("RESPONSE" + response);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: why do you add the save method in the open function? i don't want to do that ! the structure is simple in the same file with my server.js i do the connection and the save().

Comment: mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/goClass_test", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });

  var db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));

  db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("DB Connected");
  });
  var newClasse = new Classe({
    label: "hello",
    level: "level",
  });

  newClasse.save();      //even this works

Comment: you mean  you didn' change anything from my code? and it work as normal ?

Comment: i added the Server.js @Sivaraj P. please check in the question.

Comment: same code seems to be working fine. please check the lines which are commented and the files related to the commented lines

Comment: The commented lines are just routes for some pages that's all !! what wrong with that?